# ToolTip steals focus from ContextHelp

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Using Win7 and Delphi XE2 I have an application that exhibits the following:

1. The Main Form opens a modal form.
2. Application.HelpContext is called from the modal form on a buttonClick event.
3. The Help form appears and does not cover the button just clicked.
4. The mouse cursor is left on the button long enough for the tooltip to appear
5. On the appearance of the button's tooltip the help form loses focus and disappears behind the application.

This behavior confuses my users.  Any ideas?

Comment: What help system are you using?

Comment: And you are using the built in `HtmlHelpViewer` unit?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour

Comment: It's possible that [MainFormOnTaskbar + tooltip causes focus-stealing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836899/mainformontaskbar-tooltip-causes-focus-stealing) is another, reproducible, manifestation of this problem?