# MainFormOnTaskbar + tooltip causes focus-stealing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, z-order

I built the code below using Delphi XE2. It creates Form1, and Form1 immediately creates an instance of Form2. When I press the button on Form2 a second Form2 is created.

Now if I hover the mouse over the button on this second, topmost, Form2 and wait for the tooltip to appear, the moment the tooltip appears, the **first** Form2 comes to the front, stealing focus.

The problem occurs only if `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` is `True`. It also relies on the first Form2 being created from Form1's `FormCreate` method. If I use `PostMessage()` to delay the creation of the first Form2 until the application has finished initialising, the problem goes away.

I'd like to understand why this is happening. I have already learned that Delphi's Application object handles a lot of things including hint display, and I know that Delphi can recreate a window's handle during initialisation, but I haven't been able to follow this through to explain fully the behaviour described above (or indeed whether the above two facts are even relevant).

**Project1.dpr**

```
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1},
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True; // False makes problem go away
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Vcl.Forms, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    procedure CreateForm2;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CreateForm2;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateForm2;
var
  frm : TForm2;
begin
  frm := TForm2.Create(Application); // (Could pass Self - makes no difference)
  frm.Show;
end;

end.
```

**Unit2.pas**

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses
  Vcl.Forms, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, WinApi.Windows;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton; // This button has a hint
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation
uses
  System.SysUtils, Unit1;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.CreateForm2;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key issue here is that the first instance of `TForm2` is created as window that is owned by the application window, `Application.Handle`. And here I am referring to the [Windows meaning of owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows). In VCL language this is known as the popup parent.

Now, when you create that first `TForm2` instance, the `Application.MainForm` property is still `nil`. And because you did not explicitly assign `PopupParent`, the code in `TCustomForm.CreateParams` sets the owner to be the application window.

You simply do not want your windows to be owned by the hidden application window. This is the reason why that first `TForm2` instance sometimes appears behind all the other windows, in particular behind your main form. It has simply been created with the wrong owner.

The form that is owned by `Application.Handle` gets shown in `THintWindow.ActivateHint`. That happens due to the line that reads `ParentWindow := Application.Handle`. This is followed by a call to `SetWindowPos(Handle, ...)` which results in the incorrectly owned form coming to the front. Presumably that form comes to the front because it is also owned by `Application.Handle`. Right now I don't have a clear explanation for the precise mechanism, but I don't find that terribly interesting because the form is clearly setup wrongly.

In any case, the fundamental problem is that you have created a window that is incorrectly owned. The solution therefore is to make sure that the window is owned correctly. Do that by assigning the `PopupParent`. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateForm2;
var
  frm : TForm2;
begin
  frm := TForm2.Create(Application); // (Could pass Self - makes no difference)
  frm.PopupParent := Self;
  frm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I set Params.WndParent explicitly in TForm2.CreateParams instead of PopupParent, because then it's impossible to create a TForm2 without setting the parent. My TForm1 is actually hidden (and each TForm2 has its own Taskbar button) so I wasn't sure Form1.Handle was necessarily appropriate. Raymond Chen says [never use GetDesktopWindow; use 0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx). In testing 0, Form1.Handle and even Application.Handle all worked. It just seems necessary that each TForm2 has the _same_ owner. So I settled on 0.

Comment: Incidentally, Peter Below [disagrees on not using GetDesktopWindow here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!msg/borland.public.delphi.winapi/7mNoFJpYTGQ/62DpjPRf9-kJ).

Comment: If the main form is hidden, then `0` is the right thing to use. Controlling it via `WndParent` is a sound move too. As for `GetDesktopWindow`, Raymond is correct. Peter Below is just making the same mistake that so many people make. The mistake that Raymond describes.